# Woocommerce move notices on account login page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce outpuits a number of error/info notices on multiple pages. Normally this is handles by `<? wc_print_notices() ?>`, and so is nice and easy to reposition within a custom template. However, on the woocommerce account login page (form-login.php), there is no reference to `<? wc_print_notices() ?>` and therefore I cannot reposition. How are they automatically being output, and is there a way to overide them?

Answer (score 0):

error, success and notice html file exist in templates/notices and include by some function, filter and action. for example woocommerce_before_customer_login_form action for login form.

Comment: Is there a way I can move them?

Comment: move do_action('woocommerce_before_customer_login_form') from top of form-login page